# Firefox Inspector - how to change from RGB to HEX color display?

Tags: css, firefox, hex, rgb, inspector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop Firefox rendering inline colours in rgb() form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987645/stop-firefox-rendering-inline-colours-in-rgb-form)

When using the Inspector within Firefox 13 (Mac), it displays all CSS color values in (stoopid) RGB.  Is there a way to force it to display color values in HEX only?  I can't find anything anywhere about this, but I find it hard to believe I'm the only one with this issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Theres probably an option somewhere but is it really that hard to convert?

Comment: no option that I can find and am not interested in having to convert 100s of different colors per day. ;)

Comment: See this duplicate [**SO Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1987645/1195891) here.

Comment: Thx, but I already saw that one and that's not a duplicate question. Nor is the accepted answer an answer to mine. But thx. ;)

Comment: I should also add that I suspect (sigh) that there is no answer to this.  But I hold out hope that someone out there has uncovered some method (hack) to get FF to display in hex.